# pgAdmin 4: create view without defining schema

Tags: postgresql, sql-view, pgadmin-4, schema

I have a database containing the official cadastral surveying of hundreds of counties. For every county I have created a new schema named state_zipcode_countyname. As all my db entries have the same structure, I would like to create distinct views using the underlying relationships.

For example, the surfaces' type definition is stored in an external table "surftype". Thus, over the following code I can create a new view to use:

```
SELECT p.fid,
    p.geometry,
    a.type
   FROM state1_12345_mycounty.surfaces p,
    state1_12345_mycounty.surftype a
  WHERE (a.fid = p.atype);
```

However, as I have hundreds of schemas and multiple views per schema, I would like to omit defining "state1_12345_mycounty" in every view. Instead, I'd like to only browse the schema in which the view is stored, so that I can copy-paste my views quicker and easier.

Comment: Without knowing the *why*'s of your *schema galore*, to me this seems to be an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); it is an anti-pattern in relational data analytics to introduce a folder-like hierarchy to split data semantically, and as you can see, it is rather tedious to work with. You'd be better off (in every way: handling, performance, maintenance) with having a single table of all your `surfaces`, where you have a set of indexed columns (`state`, `zipcode` & `name`) to query by semantics.

Comment: Write the sql view statement without the schema and set the search-path (i.e. default schema) with "SET search_path = MySchemaName;".  Then execute your create view sql code and it will be created using the default schema.